# Uploading an image to php server from iphone

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, nsmutableurlrequest, nsmutabledata

I am trying to upload an image to server

following is iphone and php code

```
    // create request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:30];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY";
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:POST_URL,BASE_URL, [Utilities myUserId],@"", TYPE_IMAGE];

    // set Content-Type in HTTP header
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    // post body
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [params setObject:self.chatBox.text forKey:@"comment"];

    // add params (all params are strings)
    for (NSString *param in params)
    {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

    if (picData)
    {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n", @"uploadedfile"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:picData];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    // set URL
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (connection)
    {
        [self dismissKeyboard];
    }
```

PHP Code is

```
   $directoryPath = "userId_" . $userId;
    $this->makeDir("uploads/images/" . $directoryPath);
    $this->makeDir("uploads/thumbs/" . $directoryPath);

    $val = $userId .'_' . time() . ".jpg";
    $mainPath  = "uploads/images/" . "image_" . $val;
    $thumbPath = "uploads/thumbs/" . "thumb_" . $val;

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $mainPath))
        return true;
    else
        return false;


    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $mainPath))
```

is returning false. what can be wrong.

```
  ["userfile"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "dr.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["error"]=>
    int(1)
    ["size"]=>
    int(0)
  }
```

Comment: Is directory uploads/images and uploads/thumbs getting made? Do you have permission to do so?

Comment: they are already made, i have already set Permissions 777. I don't know what else is the isse, i have tested, the    $file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']); gives correct name so upload is ok

Comment: if you var_dump($_FILES) before the if statement, whats the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file size you are submitting exceeds the upload_max_filesize set in your php.ini, this can be determined by your var_dump() and examining the error key, which in this case = 1

```
Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.
```

From the docs - the default upload_max_filesize is 2MB

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Common pitfalls:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php

Comment: I have edited the php.ini and changed the default val to 200M but the result is same. error is still same :(

Comment: the error key is still int(1) ? How large is the file you are trying to upload?

Comment: 2697777 bytes, mabye i need to restart apache?

Comment: yea once you change ini you gotta restart apache